# Making a bean primary without annotation or xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

My project has a dependency on another one, and imports beans from it (using `@ImportResource("foo.xml")`).

`foo.xml` defines two datasources (`datasource1` and `datasource2`), I would like to make `datasource1` a primary (so all auto-configurations of Spring Boot will work).

Is it possible? I found out that there is a [`DefaultListableBeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html) that has [`determinePrimaryCandidate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#determinePrimaryCandidate-java.util.Map-java.lang.Class-) method.
So the idea is to create my own ListableBeanFactory, that would extend the `DefaultListableBeanFactory`, but how to force Spring Boot to use my implementation?

Or maybe there is another, easier way to mark a given bean as `primary` (without changing the configuration where it is defined).

Comment: Can you create a new data source bean in your project and inject your `datasource1` as argument? Then, you can annotate this method with `@Primary` and simply return the `datasource1`. Please, let me know if I understood your problem.

Comment: @MikeWojtyna I tried that, but it doesn't work. I get message that I have two beans and Spring can't decide which one to use.

Comment: Use @Qualifier to differentiate between your beans and name your primary bean. I'll try to prepare a working example for you later.

Comment: @MikeWojtyna I tried with `@Qualifier`, but I still have a problem - 2 beans with same type and Spring can't decide which one to use. That's why I was thinking of intercepting the registration of a bean and marking it as `Primary`.

Comment: I've just prepared a working example - everything works as intended. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration in your project, which builds a new data source annotated as `@Primary` bean. This new data source will be the `datasource1`, which will be injected by spring to the new data source factory method. Here you have the working example.

The config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BeanSpringExampleApplication
{

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    public FakeDataSource dataSource1()
    {
        return new FakeDataSource("dataSource1");
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    public FakeDataSource dataSource2()
    {
        return new FakeDataSource("dataSource2");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FakeDataSource primaryDataSource(
        @Qualifier("dataSource1") FakeDataSource dataSource1)
    {
        return dataSource1;
    }
}
```

Here you see three beans (using `FakeDataSource` class), which simulate your situation. The `primaryDataSource` bean factory method simply returns the `dataSource1` (it's just a mere data source selector).

The `FakeDataSource` is just a placeholder, to make example runnable:

```
public class FakeDataSource
{
    private final String fakeProperty;

    public FakeDataSource(String id)
    {
        fakeProperty = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fakeProperty
     */
    public String getFakeProperty()
    {
        return fakeProperty;
    }
}
```

Finally, a test which proves everything is working:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BeanSpringExampleApplicationTests
{
    @Autowired
    private FakeDataSource fakeDataSource;

    @Test
    public void should_AutowirePrimaryDataSource() throws Exception
    {
        assertEquals("dataSource1", fakeDataSource.getFakeProperty());
    }

}
```